# How to use a JavaScript variable inside a JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have `var a = 5;` in my JavaScript code.

Now, I have to send JSON data somewhere on button press

```
$('#buy-store').click(function() {
    fbq('track', 'ClickBuyInStore', {
        value : a
    });
});
```

The JSON contains JavaScript variable `a` . But I'm not able to use that using above code.

So, how to use a JavaScript variable inside a JSON file.

Comment: The above should work. The error is somewhere else. BTW: theres not yet JSON involved...

Comment: 1) check that the variable is not declared after your code
2) check your variable is not conflicting with any other variable with same name

Comment: @Jonasw Arn't the key value pairs inside the curly braces JSON?

Comment: Also make sure the var a  is declared globally and not within a function : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var You can console.log(a) just before fbq() just to verify if the a variable is accessible here.

Comment: @Justcode checked. It's ok. thanks for suggesting

Comment: No, thats just a Javascript Object Literal. *J*ava*S*cript *O*bject *N*otation is just a way to store these js objects in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse(PUT_IN_YOUR_JSON) and say for example

```
var myJSON = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');
myJSON.a = 5; // myJSON.amount = a;
```

If u want it back to a string then: `JSON.stringify(myJSON);`

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that :

```
{"user":{"name":"bla bla","email":function(){return email;}}}
```